# Create matching of row and column entries such that values are maximized

Tags: algorithm, optimization, match

Currently I am facing the following optimization problem and I cant seem to find the right applicable algorithm for this. This has to do with some of the combinatorial optimzation problems such as the knapsack problem but my mathematical knowledge is limited to that extent.

assume we have a list of the following words: ["apple", "banana", "cookie", "donut", "ear", "force"] Further, assume we have a dataset of texts which, among others, include these words. At some point I compute a cofrequency matrix, that is, a matrix of each of the word combinations the frequency in which the words combine together in all of the files. e.g. `cofreq("apple", "banana") = (amount of files which have apple and banana)/(total files)`. Therefore, `cofreq(apple, banana) = cofreq(banana, apple)`. We ignore `cofreq(apple, apple)`

Assume we have the following computed matrix (as an image, adding tables seems to be impossible): [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU8qb.png)

The goal now is to create unique word pairs such that the word frequencies are maximized and each of the word pairs have a "partner" (We assume we have an even number of words). In this example it would be:

```
(apple, force) 0.4
(cookie, donut) 0.5
(banana, ear) 0.05
------------------+--
.95
```

In this case I did it by hand but I know that there is a good algorithm for it, but I cant seem to find it. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in the form of a research paper or such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [maximum weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) algorithm to compute this maximal sum pairing.

The table you have in input can be seen as the adjacency matrix of a graph, where the values in the table correspond to the graph's edges weight. You can do it since the `cofreq` value is commutative (meaning `cofreq(apple, banana) == cofreq(banana, apple)`).

The matching algorithm you can use here is called the [blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm). It is not trivial, but very elegant. If you have some experience in implementing complex algorithms, you can implement it. Otherwise, there exists implementations of it in graph libraries for most of the common laguages.